# Background: url in CSS not working

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and was hoping someone could help me understand what I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to get an image to show up but it seems that no matter what I do it refuses to display on my page. Can someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Image saved in: `Users/NenaH77/assignment/images/sitebg.jpg`.

Css file is saved under: `Users/NenaH77/assignment/css/style.css`

```
body{ 
    background: url('../images/sitebg.jpg') no-repeat top top #31b8ea; 
   }
```

By having `../images` I thought the image saved in the folder was suppose to go up 2 levels and into my css folder so I don't understand why my image isn't showing up :(

Comment: And where is the html file?

Comment: @Musa The location of the HTML file doesn't matter - when referencing a relative URL from within a CSS file, it's relative to the CSS file, not to the page.

Comment: Your linking relation is OK. Your situation is from another point. User MrSlayer got a point, your .css declaration is not valid. Start with this and come back if it didn't fix.

Answer (score 5):

Your CSS background declaration is invalid:

`top top` should be `top` or `top left` or some other [valid combination of positions](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds/#background-position).

Try :

```
body { 
    background: url('../images/sitebg.jpg') no-repeat 0 0 #31b8ea scroll; 
}
```

Comment: I removed the top top and changed it to top but that didn't work.

Comment: Consider separating your background properties to long-hand notation (i.e. `background-image: url('../images/sitebg.jpg'); background-repeat: no-repeat; ...`) to see if you can figure out exactly which property is not working. Knowing how to debug problems will go a long way in learning how CSS works, or any new language, for that matter.

Answer (score 2):

You <del>need</del> *should probably* put the background color first.

```
body { background: #31b8ea url('../images/sitebg.jpg') no-repeat top }
```

Mr. Slayer gave you the right answer though.

Comment: This is not a true statement.  The background color does not need to be put first.

Comment: Color don't **need** to be first.. [was edited, now the code it's ok, but duplicate..., and the color still don't need to be at start.. the problem was the `top top` declaration]

Comment: Well, I'll be damned.

Comment: The order of shorthand properties doesn't usually matter, except in certain situations such as `margin` and `padding`.

Comment: The order of shorthand properties doesn't matter with background. I wonder why the upvote.

Answer (score 0):

To go up 2 levels do this

```
background: url('../../images/sitebg.jpg') no-repeat top top #31b8ea;
```

Comment: My image still didn't come up with that either. I didn't realize I could go up that many more levels. Will have to keep that in mind. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This will work. You can see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jlnewnam/QDxb8/).

```
body { background: url(../../img/image.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;}
```

This will also take you up two levels...

Comment: Thank you everyone. I've tried everyone's suggestions but I'm still having no luck :(

Comment: Why don't you try posting a link to your live site? Can you upload these files to a server? We'd love to help you, but debugging this live would be much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same problem. What worked for me was putting the full path of the image from my pc, instead of from just inside the project folder.

So in this case use

```
body { background: url('C:/Users/NenaH77/assignment/images/sitebg.jpg')}
```

Instead of

```
body { background: url('../images/sitebg.jpg')}
```